# connecting to license server in free version of Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have downloaded the latest version of Unity,but whenever I try to open it, it shows an error displaying "Error connecting to license server", although I always have internet connection while opening it. Does anyone know how to get over this problem?

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Don't misuse it.